# Prevents users from locking the screen?

Tags: lock-screen, 17.04

My kids all have an account on the computer.  Problem is, they tend to use the "lock" (CTRL+ALT+L) functionality instead of logging out, and then the next kid in the family has to come looking for me or their sibling to unlock the computer.  To do so, I ssh into the computer and manually run "sudo service lightdm restart".

I would like to do one or more of the following:

- remove the "lock" option in the top-right gear menu
- disable CTRL+ALT+L
- make it so if they lock the screen, it automatically runs something like "service lightdm restart" so they're completely logged out

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

## You have a couple of options:

**Option 1:**

Open a terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

That command disables the screen lock feature. You can also control this setting from the dconf-editor (may require install). You'll find that this setting is just one of the lockdown settings available
[image: Screenshot from 2017-04-24 15-18-01.png]

---

**Option 2:**
You might try setting a custom keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> that overrides the default function and causes the account to log out instead of lock. This approach obviously won't remove the lock option from the "top-right gear menu."

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

- run unity-tweak-tool
- click on System -> Security
- toggle "Desktop lock" (add checkbox to prevent it)
- toggle "User switching" (add checkbox to prevent it)

**Second solution**, the same thing but with a different tool:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

- run dconf-editor
- browse to /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown
- toggle disable-lock-screen
- toggle disable-user-switching

**Third solution**, again the same thing but done from the command-line without the use of a GUI:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-lock-screen true
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-user-switching true
dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/
```